# How to handle fixed top bar and body section has input field with cursor

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, cursor-position

[Attached image for clearification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhCnD.png)There is one use case: 
                     I have Header section - fixed position
                        I have body section of each step
                     I have Footer section
Now problem is that I have input field in body section with scroll. When scroll to bottom after focusing in input field, cursor goes on Header are with blinking.

This happening only with IE11.

Comment: Can you share code for more clarification..

Comment: Only description of the issue will not help us to understand it properly.If possible for you than please try to post any sample code which we can try to test with IE and other browsers to check the issue. Than we can try to provide any suggestions for it. Thanks for your understanding.